# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:Invalid content was found starting with element 'bean'

Tags: java, spring, xsd

I've tried solving this issue for hours. 
When I run my code I get an error saying:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:Invalid content was found starting with element 'bean' One of 
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":include-filter, 
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":exclude-filter}' is expected.

I've looked around alot for answers, some suggestions were that one should make sure the right versions are used. I use the same version in my xml as in my pom file. (I'm using maven with eclipse btw).

Any suggestions on what the problem might be?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.7.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.7.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mywebbapp.filemanagement">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean"
        id="FileStoreFactory">
        <property name="FileStore"
            value="org.mywebbapp.filemanagement.FileStoreFactory">
        </property>
    </bean>
    <alias alias="FH" name="FileHandler" />
</context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<context:component-scan>` should not have `<bean>` elements nested within.

Try:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mywebbapp.filemanagement"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean"
    id="FileStoreFactory">
    <property name="FileStore"
        value="org.mywebbapp.filemanagement.FileStoreFactory">
    </property>
</bean>
<alias alias="FH" name="FileHandler" />
```

Comment: should have an end tag for <context:component-scan base-package="org.mywebbapp.filemanagement"/>

Comment: should *not* have an end tag for an xml element ending with `/>`